# Programmes crashing in OpenBSD 6.1

Tags: firefox, openbsd, thunar

I run OpenBSD 6.1 and some programmes like thunar and firefox keep crashing randomly. Not all programms crash, however. I ran memtest, I increased datasize-max and datasize-cur both to 2048M in /etc/login.conf. I now ran out of ideeas to troubleshoot. Please help!

PS: I run 6.1 stable, generic kernel and binary packages (not ports). Firefox - I tried both the package from the official repos and the one from Landry Breuil.

When ran from the terminal, the output is:

```
370[~]$ thunar

(thunar:60027): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large

(thunar:60027): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large
371[~]$ firefox                                                                

firefox:/usr/local/lib/libicuuc.so.12.0: 
/usr/local/lib/libicudata.so.12.0 : WARNING: symbol(icudt58_dat) size mismatch, relink your program

(firefox:41143): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown key font_name in /home/spacelander/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
firefox:/usr/local/lib/libicuuc.so.12.0: /usr/local/lib/libicudata.so.12.0 : WARNING: symbol(icudt58_dat) size mismatch, relink your program

(/usr/local/lib/firefox-55.0.3/firefox:23946): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown key font_name in /home/spacelander/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

Edit2: [dmesg output](https://pastebin.com/rxxJXbTH)

Comment: If you start these programs from a terminal, do you get any error message in the terminal when they crash?  Are you following 6.1-stable and have you installed from binary (stable) packages?

Comment: Edited the original question.

Comment: Copy/paste the output of `dmesg`.

Comment: done, reedited the question

Comment: I thought that the problem was related to wxallowed but the `dmesg` doesn't show any wx error, so I can't help you.

Comment: Are those the messages at the actual crash? They're just warnings...

Comment: You _do_ get some warnings about mismatched libraries. Maybe do `pkg_add -u` to make sure packages are all up to date?

Comment: oh, sorry, no, I forgot to mention. It's the output when I start the apps. I couldn't find a reliable way to get them to crash. And all packages are up to date.